# cons two elements outputs the wrong result

Tags: racket, cons

```
#lang racket
```

I need to create a pair from an element and a list

however when I do `(cons 2 (list 1 2 3))` I get `(2 (1 2 3))`, I want to get `(2 . (1 2 3))`
how do I get the dot in ?

Comment: With `(cons 2 (list 1 2 3))` you don't get `(2 (1 2 3))`

Answer (score 3):

Since `(cons a b)` is the same as `(a . b)` we get that `(2 . (1 2 3))` is the same as `(cons 2 (list 1 2 3)` which is the same as `(list 2 1 2 3)`. To confirm:

```
> (cons 2 (list 1 2 3))
'(2 1 2 3)

> '(2 . (1 2 3))
'(2 1 2 3)
```

Note that the printer prints `(2 1 2 3)` and not `(2 . (1 2 3))`. The printer attempts to use the dot only when absolutely needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the syntax that explains the structure, how it's stored and how `display` would represent it.

For a list of two elements there are two ways you can represent it `(1)` and `(1 . ())`. When this list is displayed it will always prefer the one with the least parentheses. Thus `'(2 . (1 2 3))` will always be printed as `(2 1 2 3)` by `display`. If you don't want that you can make yourself a `cons-write` like:

```scm
;; displays cons always as dotted
(define (cons-write x)
  (if (pair? x)
      (begin
         (display "(")
         (cons-write (car x))
         (display " . ") ; spaces are important
         (cons-write (cdr x))
         (display ")"))
      (write x)))

(cons-write '(1 2 3 4)) ; prints (1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . ()))))
```